# How to choose option from dropdown list in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to  click in Selenium on each option.

```
<div class="el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap" style="margin-bottom: -17px; margin-right: -17px;" xpath="1">
  <ul class="el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list">
  <!---->
    <li class="el-select-dropdown__item selected hover" style="">
      <span>Part number</span>
    </li>
    <li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
      <span>Work order number</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried by Actions class, Select class with no effect.
While I click on the list is visible, but I am unable to locate the element. Selenium does no see it.

Comment: <div class="el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap" style="margin-bottom: -17px; margin-right: -17px;" xpath="1"><ul class="el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list"><!----><li class="el-select-dropdown__item selected hover" style=""><span>Part number</span></li> <li class="el-select-dropdown__item"><span>Work order number</span></li></ul></div>

Comment: here is the structure

Answer (score 0):

To Select `Work order number` from `dropdown` induce `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` and following xpath options.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap']/ul[@class='el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list']//li[./span[text()='Work order number']]")));
element.click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap']/ul[@class='el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list']//li//span[text()='Work order number']")));
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[starts-with(@class,'el-scrollbar__view')]"));    
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//li[starts-with(@class,'el-select-dropdown__item')]"));

public void selectOption(String option){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropdown));
    dropdown.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(options));
    for(WebElement element : options){
         if(element.getText().equals(option))
              element.click();
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Please take the commentary out of the code block and add some explanation for the code and how it answers the question.

Comment: Use Explicit wait to wait for element to be clickable and visible. Call method selectOption("Part number"). It will click on drop down list and the String which is passed will be compared and if it matched it will select that option from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[starts-with(@class,'el-scrollbar__view')]"));
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//li[starts-with(@class,'el-select-dropdown__item')]"));

    @Test
    public void testCase1() {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropdown));
        dropdown.click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(options));
        for (WebElement element : options) {
            element.click();
        }
    }
```